# word vba clear text on control exit

Tags: vba, ms-word

Ok so I have a word 2013 document that will be restricted from editing when the users fill the form out.

At the end of this form is a checkbox which when checked, a date field will automatically fill in todays date.

So what I have done so far is wrote a Macro when the user exits any content control does the following. I should clarify that the code that fills in the date is fine:

```
Private Sub Document_ContentControlOnExit(ByVal ContentControl As ContentControl, _
        Cancel As Boolean)
    Dim cc As ContentControl
    For Each cc In ActiveDocument.ContentControls
        // This works fine
        If cc.Title = "ConfirmBox" Then
            If cc.Checked = True Then
                With ActiveDocument.Bookmarks("DateBox").Range
                    .InsertAfter Format(Date, "dd mm yyyy")
                End With
                // This doesn't work
            Else
                Set datebox= ActiveDocument.Bookmarks("DateBox").Range
                datebox.Text = "test"
            End If
            Exit For
        End If
    Next cc
End Sub
```

What I want to happen is that when the user unchecks the checkbox, any text is cleared from the field so basically it resets itself. What would be the best way to achieve this?

When I try to do it the way written in the code above, I get an error code '6028' saying "The Range cannot be deleted"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When I run the code above, it inserts the date correctly when the box is checked. When clearing the box it inserts the text, but doesn't overwrite the date. Next time the box is checked, the code will fail because the Bookmark doesn't exist.

The reason that text in the Else statement isn't overwriting the date is that the date is being inserted after the bookmark rather than inside. You may have chosen this option because inserting the text in to the bookmark range causes the bookmark to be deleted. That is why the code fails if you check the box a second time.

This is quite a common scenario, and the solution is to store the bookmark range, then insert the text, then reinsert the bookmark as below:

```
Private Sub Document_ContentControlOnExit(ByVal ContentControl As ContentControl, Cancel As Boolean)
    Dim cc As ContentControl

    For Each cc In ActiveDocument.ContentControls
        ' This works fine
        If cc.Title = "ConfirmBox" Then
            If cc.Checked = True Then
                Dim BMRange  As Range
                'Identify current Bookmark range and insert text
                 Set BMRange = ActiveDocument.Bookmarks("DateBox").Range
                 BMRange.Text = Format(Date, "dd mm yyyy")
                'Re-insert the bookmark
                 ActiveDocument.Bookmarks.Add "DateBox", BMRange

            Else
                'Identify current Bookmark range and insert text
                 Set BMRange = ActiveDocument.Bookmarks("DateBox").Range
                 BMRange.Text = "test"
                'Re-insert the bookmark
                 ActiveDocument.Bookmarks.Add "DateBox", BMRange
            End If
            Exit For
        End If
    Next cc

End Sub
```

If you want the bookmark to remain in the document for future use, then you'll need to ensure that you follow the same pattern every time you update the text in the bookmark.

Comment: Thanks for your help. However, on BMRange.Text = Format(Date, "dd mm yyyy") and on BMRange.Text = "test", I get the same error  code '6028' saying "The Range cannot be deleted". Is there anything to the actual document that I need to do?

Comment: @DigM Is the document protected (eg to only allow the user to fill in Form Fields)? If so, you are also unable to write to a Bookmark in a protected section of the document (just as the user would be unable to edit text there). If this is the case, you can either add an unprotected section to the document and add the bookmark there, or use a FormField instead of a Bookmark.

Comment: I used a content control instead and that worked. Thanks @Jane!